# Nested combinations #2

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have *A* bags, each with *B* red balls and *C* black balls. I choose *D* balls from each bag, where *D* is an odd number. If, of the *D* balls pulled from each bag, the majority is red, I put one red ball into a separate "chosen balls" bag; if the majority is black, I put a black ball in. After going through each bag, I then choose *E* balls from the "chosen balls" bag. How do I calculate the probability of choosing an equal number of red and black balls? (Yes, *E* is presumed to be even.)

Comment: Why not just say that you are pulling a single ball from each bag?  Isn't that the same thing, roughly?

Comment: I removed the tags Game Theory, Combinatorial Game Theory and Voting Theory, as the question does not really relate to those.

Comment: @RonGordon: Cf., My question-comment to Your answer below. If You are correct, I am far more appreciative than You could possibly imagine; I just need to make sure.